# How to fix: alternate name are improperly configured Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server

Tags: html, github, server, dns, hosting

I got this problem when i was hosting my personal website.

when i tried to save my coustom domain this error occur: alternate name are improperly configured
Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.